# Expected value of a Poisson random variable

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

Here is the question, it is SOA number 280: The number of burglaries occurring on Burlington Street during a one-year period is Poisson distributed with mean $1$.

Calculate the expected number of burglaries on Burlington Street in a one-year period, given that there are at least two burglaries.

My work so far:

$$E(X|x=2)={\sum_{x=2}^{\infty}xp(x)\over 1-p(0)-p(1)} $$

$$={\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}xp(x)-0p(0)-p(1)\over 1-p(0)-p(1)}$$

$$={\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}xp(x)-p(1)}\over 1-p(0)-p(1)$$

My question is solving this summation. I've checked my work with the solution and it is right, but I don't understand how they solve the summation. Admittedly I've always had difficulty with these things. Any hints would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: also any hints on how to make my equations not so tiny so people can actually see them would be great.

From just looking at it, I decided to try this

$$p(x)={e^{-1}1^x\over x!}$$

so I get

$$\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}{xe^{-1}1^{x}\over x!}-e^{-1}=\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}e^{-1}({x1^{x}\over x!}-1)$$

But from here I am stuck.

Comment: To make your equations in "display" format, which will make them larger and on a line by themselves, surround them by two dollar signs on each side.  I've edited your post for this.

Comment: Can you simplify $\frac{x}{x!}$?

Comment: Question: I made the mistake of saying $\sum_{x=0}^{\infty} xP(X|X\geq 2) = \sum_{x=0}^{\infty} x\frac{P(X=x, X\geq 2)}{P(X\geq 2)} = \sum_{x=0}^{\infty} x\frac{P(X\geq 2)}{P(X\geq 2) } $. What is wrong with this argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your numerator you have $\sum_{x=0}^\infty x p(x)$.  But $p$ is the pdf of a Poisson random variable with mean 1, so $\sum_{x=0}^\infty x p(x)$ is the expectation of a Poisson random variable with mean $1$, which is 1.

Comment: so it just becomes $1+\sum_{x=0}^{\infty} -p(1)$? Does this just simplify to $1-p(1)$? And if so, how?

Comment: Be a little more careful about parentheses.  The numerator is $\left( \sum_{x=0}^\infty xp(x) \right) - p(1)$.  The $p(1)$ is not part of the sum.  So the entire sum within parentheses is $1$, and the numerator is $1 - p(1)$.

Comment: Ahh, I so I reduced my summation down to $x=0$ properly but when I subtract $0p(0)$ and $1p(1)$ they come out of the summation?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: Just to make sure I'm understanding this correctly, if I had $\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}xp(x)$ I can make this ($\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}xp(x)) - 0p(0) = \sum_{x=0}^{\infty}xp(x) =$ the mean?